# how can devaluation of a nation's currency lead to increase in government expenditure, hence facilitating economic growth

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, supply-and-demand, international-trade

how can devaluation of a nation's currency  lead to increase in government expenditure, hence facilitating economic growth.

I was reading through a textbook and saw that the devaluation of a nation's currency  can lead to increase in government expenditure, hence facilitating economic growth.... But it wasn't really explained. How is this possible please? I need an economist perspective. I'm an accountant.

Comment: What was the exchange rate regime? That is very important information to answer your question.

Comment: It is Floating type

Comment: Floating exchange rates

Comment: Is it something to do with making it easier for foreign entities to finance the government's debt @BBKing?

Comment: With a fixed exchange rate regime the government might have to react in some way to maintain the exchange rate possibly. Even then it would be a bit farfetched though. With a float, its even harder to make the case that government expenditure should increase. Maybe there are some other details that explain the statement, but there is surely not a standard link here between government expenditure and exchange rates per se.